# rotateY does not work properly on HTC One with android 4.1.2 default browser

Tags: android, css, html, webkit, rotation

I prepared this fiddle to demonstrate my problem:
http://jsfiddle.net/Nvy3F/

```
<div id="cube">
        <div id="face1"></div>
        <div id="face2"></div>
        <div id="face3"></div>
        <div id="face4"></div>
        <div id="face5"></div>
       <div id="face6"></div> 
</div>

            @keyframes mb_rotate {
            0% {transform:rotateY(0deg);}
            25% {transform:rotateY(90deg);}
            50% {transform:rotateY(180deg);}
            75% {transform:rotateY(270deg);}                
            100% {transform: rotateY(360deg);}
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes mb_rotate {
            0% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg);}
            25% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg);}
            50% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);}
            75% {-webkit-transform:rotateY(270deg);}                
            100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);}
        }         
 /*   */

        #cube {
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            width:300px;height:300px;
            transform-style:preserve-3d;
            -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;                
            /*transition:transform 1300ms linear 0s;*/
            position:relative;
            margin: 0 auto;
            animation: 10s mb_rotate infinite linear;
            -webkit-animation: 10s mb_rotate infinite linear;
        }

        #face1 {
            width:300px;height:250px;                
            transform:translateZ(125px);
            -webkit-transform:translateZ(125px);
            background:green;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            position:absolute;

        }

        #face2 {
            width:300px;height:250px;
            transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(125px);
            -webkit-transform:rotateX(90deg) translateZ(125px);
            background:red;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            position:absolute;                
        }

        #face3 {
            width:300px;height:250px;
            transform:rotateY(180deg) translateZ(125px) rotateZ(0deg);
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg) translateZ(125px) rotateZ(0deg);
            background:blue;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            position:absolute;                
        }

        #face4 {
            width:300px;height:250px;
            transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(125px) rotate(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
            -webkit-transform:rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(125px) rotate(180deg) rotateZ(180deg);
            background:yellow;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            position:absolute;                
        }

        #face5 {
            width:250px;height:250px;                
            transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(175px);
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(90deg) translateZ(175px);
            background:orange;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            position:absolute;                
        }

        #face6 {
            width:250px;height:250px;
            transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(125px);
            -webkit-transform:rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(125px);
            background:purple;
            backface-visibility:hidden;
            position:absolute;                
        }
```

If you run it on let's say Firefox desktop browser it should display rotating box (with colored sides). Box rotates around it's y-axis.

If you run it on SGS2 with android 4.1.2 on default browser it still looks good.

But...

If you run it on HTC One with android 4.1.2 on default browser it starts to disappear after rotation passes through 90 degree rotation. And then when animation is after 270 degree box appears again on the screen.

I tried a lot of approaches to this problem, searched web and still have no clue why does it happen, maybe someone can help.